# How to find out flatlist last item visible in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am working on pagination logic in my app.I am getting 10 elements in api call based on start index and end index.But here i need to find out whether list scroll to end, means after last item visible i need to call load more. I am using flatlist onEndReached, onEndReachedThreshold but after loading first 10 elements it is calling onEndReached but i haven't to scrolled to last item.

```
 <FlatList                             
    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.itemSeperator}
    data={this.state.contactCards}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => <ItemComponent itemObj={item} />}
    horizontal={false}
    ListFooterComponent={this.FlatListFooter}
    onEndReached={this.loadMore}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}                                   
  />
```

Comment: i think it's happened because your `FlatList` `height` overlapping screen height

Comment: I got a fix for this flatlist onScrollEndDrag can fix my issue, it is calling when list scrolled to bottom

Comment: its weird, `onEndReached` and `onEndReachedThreshold` is the best option for me, and my code works well like your snippet above, i dont need `onScrollEndDrag` anynore

Comment: In Native app(android/iOS) development we do like this only based on flatlist scroll

Comment: Flatlist height overlapping screen height what it means?

Comment: let say your device height 800, and you set height of FlatList 900, so device height not covered 100 of FlatList height